# "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/type/AnnotatedTypeMetadata"

Tags: spring-mvc, jakarta-mail

```
@Bean
    public JavaMailSender mailSender() {
        JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
        mailSender.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        mailSender.setHost("smtp.googlemail.com");
        mailSender.setPort(465);
        mailSender.setUsername("XXXXXXXXX@gmail.com");
        mailSender.setPassword("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", true);
        properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", true);
        mailSender.setJavaMailProperties(properties);
        return mailSender;
    }
```

I am trying to send mail using javamailsender for that i configured the above code using annotations after that I get the "`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/type/AnnotatedTypeMetadata`" exception any suggestions appriciate.

Answer (score 8):

It seems dependency [spring-core](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core) is missing. You should add this `jar`.

Answer (score 2):

Or using maven choose a dependency from here: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.6.RELEASE</version>
 </dependency>
```

Comment: It did not work in my case.
It keeps saying _Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.core.ResolvableTypeProvider_

Although I have
**spring-core** in my pom

Comment: @JanKhonski When I had this error, the solution I posted helped me. I guess you might be missing another Spring module. Good luck!

Comment: I managed to fix it. We had many spring libraries of different versions. I excluded all of them, and added them again with the same vrsion - 4.2.5-RELEASE in my case. It worked!